# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does the following implication hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x$.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$.  Numbers $N$ satisfying the equation $\sigma(N)=2N$ are called *perfect numbers*.  Euler showed that an *odd perfect number* must have the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Here is my question:

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with Euler prime $q$, does the following implication hold?
>   $$\bigg(q^k < n \iff \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \iff \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}\bigg) \implies \left(q^k < n\right)$$

From an answer to this earlier [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713035), I know that the converse 
$$\left(q^k < n\right) \implies \bigg(q^k < n \iff \sigma(q^k) < \sigma(n) \iff \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{n} < \dfrac{\sigma(n)}{q^k}\bigg)$$
holds.