# Specific evidence for or against the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture on odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, big-list, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918871/28816) to an earlier (and related) MSE question summarizes what appears to be the first documented "evidence" against the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=1$, if $q^k n^2$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special / Euler prime $q$ (satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$).  (Specifically, via exhaustion of all possible cases, it appears plausible that $k>1$ must hold true.)

On the other hand, for the [Descartes spoof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124167) (which is probably the closest we will ever get to an "actual odd perfect number")
$$\mathscr{D} = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}\cdot{22021} = 198585576189$$
the quasi-Euler prime $22021$ (which is actually composite) has exponent $1$.  Additionally, the non-Euler part ${3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2}$ of $\mathscr{D}$ can be (directly) shown to be [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816), a condition which is known to be equivalent to the [Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf).

So here is my question:

> What other evidence or heuristic do you know of that supports (or otherwise does not support) the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture for odd perfect numbers?

One piece of evidence/heuristic per answer only, please.